# Объединение таблиц из разных баз данных sqlite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3, объединение

Имеется папка с конечным числом баз данных sqlite3 в ней. Все они имеют имеют одинаковую структуру, носят имя по следующему принципу: part***.db, где *** - номер части базы данных. В этой же папке есть файл БД log.db, содержащий в себе таблицу, где сказано, сколько таких частей находится в папке. Каким образом можно выполнить объединение данных из файлов part***.db в один файл? Желательно, чтобы процесс можно было автоматизировать. Спасибо.

Comment: Можно написать скрипт, который в цикле для каждой БД будет объединять их в одну. Что именно у вас не получается с таким скриптом?

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что для этого нужно выполнить SQL-запрос? Не могли ли бы Вы привести пример такого запроса?

Comment: Ну, про синтаксис SQL и запросы вы можете почитать [здесь](https://proselyte.net/tutorials/sql/sql-basic-syntax/), или загуглить. Нужно считать из log.db кол-во файлов и для каждого из них выполнить запрос всей информации из всех таблиц, при этом записывая эту информацию в новую БД.

Одним запросом это не делается. Попытайтесь сами, например на python, если не получится - дополните вопрос кодом и тогда вам обязательно помогут :)